# Does Sri Lankan need a transit visa for South Korea

Tags: transit, transit-visas, seoul, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm a Sri Lankan passport holder, currently living in china and I'm planing to go back to Sri Lanka. My flight (Korean air) from China to Colombo via South Korea.I have to stay 6h in Seoul Incheon airport to my next flight. I'm not planing to leave the airport.

Do I need any kind of visa to enter to the South Korea?

Answer (score 2):

According to Timatic, the system used by airlines, transiting without a visa is possible for:

- Passengers transiting through Seoul (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
- Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

  - This TWOV facility does not apply at Seoul (ICN).

Source: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b